# How can I meassure server size requirement?

Tags: php, memory-management, resources, webserver

Consider a regular PHP website with no Flash or other special features. Is there a measurement for server size requirements (e.g. 1 GB RAM allowing 100 people at the same time being connected)?

Comment: No. It depends too heavily on what your application actually does.

Comment: There are _many_ variables that would go into something like this.

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors. So it would be impossible to give you an answer to this question. I always use hosting which enables you to scale when needed (most of them do this).

Comment: Not really - the answer is, unfortunately, _it depends_. It'll depend on what framework you're using, how database intensive it is, how often users need to make a server call (via AJAX as well as page rendering), how well-tuned the queries are, how well-optimised the code is... However if you are on a VPS or in the cloud, you can start with a small amount of RAM, and ramp up easily as your userbase increases.

Comment: Read whole application, calculate what max size of data is stored using your application in RAM or just test it.

Comment: Does the database factor receive rather minor a major weight?

Comment: flash is client side, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far more likely you'll first face the limitations on the data level rather than on the application level. If you're using MySQL, for example, there is a [formula](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/how-do-you-calculate-mysql-max-connections-variable) allowing to calculate (roughly!) the number of connections it can serve with a certain RAM amount available and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need much ram to serve an average website, so requirements can be very low.

However, if you are considering any more than 100 users at the same time, which is quite a large amount, then it would be a good idea to profile your website, get measurements on a per user size and memory usage, and multiply to understand how it grows on your specific site.

Comment: Agree. Also you should compare traffic for 10, 50, 100, 1000 users - as the workload won't be linear. With the resulting "graph" you can guess the performance for higher amounts of users. You should also analyze the php and the database (if exists) separately.

Answer (score 0):

No, one cannot make generalizations about server size requirements without knowing more details about your situation / use-case.

Please provide more details:

- How much traffic do you intend to serve?
- What is the most common thing these visitors are doing? Browsing Pages, Creating Images, Posting Comments, etc.,
- Any other info you might have about the requirements.

Also, you can always start with a Shared Host, and then go ahead to bigger plans or cloud servers when your site grows extremely popular.